# Is it possible to create a triangle using css with all three sides of different color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a triangle in my webpage with all three sides  of it of different color ...please suggest how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SVG, like this:

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.str2 {stroke:blue;stroke-width:10;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:22.9256}
.str0 {stroke:lime;stroke-width:10;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:22.9256}
.str1 {stroke:red;stroke-width:10;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:22.9256}
.fil0 {fill:none}
```

```html
<svg width="360px" height="360px" viewBox="0 0 360 360">
 <g id="Layer_x0020_1">
  <g id="_2422114433216">
   <line class="fil0 str0" x1="180" y1="32.62" x2="9.82" y2= "327.38" />
   <line class="fil0 str1" x1="180" y1="32.62" x2="350.18" y2= "327.38" />
   <line class="fil0 str2" x1="350.18" y1="327.38" x2="9.82" y2= "327.38" />
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

This way you can pretty much do anything you like with it, like changing the colors dynamically or setting hover effect or whatever you can do with HTML elements.